# How can I get TypeScript to type-check the spread operator in React props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, static-analysis

This code properly flagged in TS:

`<MyComponent nonexistentProp="foo" />`

This code is not:

`<MyComponent { ...{ nonexistentProp: "foo" }} />`

It seems trivial for TS to check that improper props are not getting passed in - how can we enable this checking to ensure that we're passing in the expected props?

Comment: I believe this is not specific to JSX and spread. This actually can be reduced to `React.createElement<MyComponentProps>(MyComponent, { nonexistentProp: "foo" })` vs `React.createElement<MyComponentProps>(MyComponent, Object.assign({ nonexistentProp: "foo" }))` (this is what happens internally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this type checking is subject to the same constraints as regular TypeScript code:

```ts
interface Contract {
  a: string;
}

const allowed: Contract = {
  a: "bc",
};

const notAllowed: Contract = {
  a: "bc",
  b: "dc",
};

const aboutToBeAllowed = {
  a: "bc",
  b: "dc",
};

const alsoAllowed: Contract = aboutToBeAllowed;
```

The problem shown here is that TypeScript has it's limitations, in that it's a structural type system.

It is only able to enforce the constraints that us humans think it should be doing in all cases during an object literal assignment (see `notAllowed` assignment).

The `alsoAllowed` case is essentially the same as the `notAllowed` variant, but it works.  This is because the anonymous object satisfies the `Contract` constraints.

Similarly, in your TSX example, this is essentially the same behavior as regular TypeScript:

```ts
interface Props { a: string; };
const MyComponent: React.SFC<Props> = (props) => <div />;

const myCompOk1 = <MyComponent a="ab" />;

const myCompBad1 = <MyComponent a="ab" b="cd" />;

const anonPropsNoExtra = { a: "bc" };
const myCompOk2 = <MyComponent {...anonPropsNoExtra} />;

const anonPropsWithExtra = { a: "bc", b: "cd" };
const myCompOk3 = <MyComponent {...anonPropsWithExtra} />;
```

I don't believe it's possible for it to enforce it the way you're looking for

Comment: Ok - interesting, thank you for the background.  I'm able to get what I need by refactoring a bit to type-check the object before spreading it into the props.

Comment: I don't believe this answer is correct.  It states that it's not possible to achieve type-checking for spread props.  However, it is theoretically possible, and in fact was implemented as the default behavior for a short time.  See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15463 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15731

Yuit's comments in the main thread describe how they rolled it back and settled on the current default behavior that is described in the question here.  Unfortunately, I do not know how to get back to the functionality described in the link.

Comment: Was there any solution to this? I'm resorting to typing the variable before spreading it